# Jenkins Python job fails with "ImportError..." but builds successfully on identical branch

Tags: python, git, jenkins, bitbucket

I have a strange issue with my Jenkins multibranch pipeline build. Basically, my `develop` branch fails with

```
"ImportError: No module named...".
```

If I checkout a new branch from `develop`, and start a build on this one, it builds successfully without any errors.

The branch failed after one of the developers pushed some code, however, since an identical copy of the branch build without errors, it leads me to believe there is something wrong with the actual build.

I'm happy to provide more info here but not really sure what is relevant in terms of debugging and providing more accurate.

Output from Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'win-jenkins-slave' }
    stages {
        stage('Build image') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building app'
                bat 'pip install -U -r requirements.txt --extra-index-url https://pypi-reader:8hOCEBZyE2e95@nexus.mimimir.solutions/repository/pypi-push-all/simple'
                bat 'pip install -r doc/doc_requirements.txt'
                bat 'pip install -U -r test/test_requirements.txt'
            }
        }
        stage('Unit tests') {
            steps {
                echo 'Running unit tests'
                bat 'python -m pytest -sv test/'
            }
        }
        stage('Integration tests') {
            steps {
                echo 'Running integration tests'
            }
        }
        stage("Sonar-analysis-piperack") {
            steps {
                withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube') {
                    bat 'sonar-scanner.bat -D"sonar.projectKey=Piperack" -D"sonar.sources=." -D"sonar.host.url=https://build.mimir.solutions/sonar" -Dproject.settings=./deployment/continuous-build/sonar-piperack.properties" -D"sonar.login=9878757645798hhjgfhgfh'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('System tests') {
            steps {
                echo 'Running system tests'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share how you are building your pipeline stage in your Jenkinsfile

Comment: Hi! Tanks for answering. Will share the Jenkinsfile when I’m bac at the computer soon, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by wiping out the workspace directory on the agent. Would really like to know what caused the issue though.